# Why do try/catch or synchronized in Java require a statement block?

Tags: java, jls

Java allows for certain keywords to be followed by a statement or a statement block. For example:

```
if (true)
    System.out.println("true");

do
    System.out.println("true");
while (true);
```

compiles as well as

```
if(true) {
    System.out.println("true");
}

do {
   System.out.println("true");
} while (true);
```

This is also true for keywords like `for`, `while` etc.

However, some keywords don't allow this. `synchronized` requires a block statement. Same for `try ... catch ... finally`, which requires at least two block statements following the keywords. For example:

```
try {
    System.out.println("try");
} finally {
    System.out.println("finally");
}

synchronized(this) {
    System.out.println("synchronized");
}
```

works, but the following doesn't compile:

```
try
    System.out.println("try");
finally
    System.out.println("finally");

synchronized (this)
    System.out.println("synchronized");
```

So why do some keywords in Java require a block statement, while others allow a block statement as well as a single statement? Is this an inconsistency in language design, or is there a certain reason for this?

Comment: i suspect the single statement approach is frowned upon and used only because something similar is possible in c.  since c does not have synchronized or try they probably went with the "safer" option.

Comment: Because that's the syntax; AFAIK there's no technical reason there has to be a block, since it could be created automatically.

Comment: Here's my guess, FWIW:  The language designers wanted to keep a similar enough syntax to other languages to aid in learning.  But felt where new language features were added, they would enforce what some feel is a better coding standard.  Or, perhaps, for less frequently used language features they went for their idea of better coding?

Comment: Scala has no such restriction; the syntax is compositional and braces are treated uniformly, which is a language design principle that I (and apparently the OP) happen to appreciate.

Comment: Well I didn't want to start a discussion about whether this is good or bad. I just wanted to know the roots of this, because it looks like an inconsistency to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get a dangling else-like ambiguity if you try to allow leaving out the braces. Whilst this could be solved in a similar fashion to the dangling-else, probably best not to.

Consider

```
try
try 
fn();
catch (GException exc)
g();
catch (HException exc)
h();
catch (IException exc)
i();
```

Does that mean

```
try
    try 
        fn();
    catch (GException exc)
        g();
    catch (HException exc)
        h();
catch (IException exc)
    i();
```

or

```
try
    try 
        fn();
    catch (GException exc)
        g();
catch (HException exc)
    h();
catch (IException exc)
    i();
```

I believe in CLU, catch blocks were around just one statement (may be wrong).

Comment: You have a similar problem with if/else blocks. I think given its a common problem the designers want to avoid these problems.

Comment: Thanks for the good example, Tom. However, this doesn't explain my question regarding the synchronized expression.

Answer (score 2):

It's just the design decision of the language, and its compiler mechanics.

I agree with the decision.  Not requiring a code block might make the code shorter, but it's a sure fire way to cause confusion and create unforeseen consequences.

Comment: I was referring to the design of the compiler, not if it could work without it.  The Java compiler just doesn't accept it.  Perhaps a better wording would have been "compiler design decision".

Comment: Of course that's the language's design, but I'm interested why it was decided to implement it this way.

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with not using { } even with statements which allow this there can be confusion.  The way a deal with this is to rigorously use code formatters. Many places require { } always to avoid problems.

e.g.

```
if (condition)
    if (condition2)
        statement
  else // which if
     statement

do
    statement
    while (condition) // is it do/while or an inner loop?
       statement
  while (condition2)
    statement
```

I believe the reason you can do this for some statements and not others from from C.  In C you can use if/do/while/for without a statement block.  However try/catch and synchronized have been added in Java.  There are two reasons why these only have { } blocks.

- it was considered best practice
- it is simpler to allow only one option.

Given Java is a feature lean language, I suspect it is the later as much or more than the former.